# How to put an array variable containing language file in a library or in helpers to be in every controller file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array public variable loaded identically in every controller class that I have. The array variable contains language file to be passed to the view file. 
Sample:`public $data; $this->data = array('lbl_first_name'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_first_name'));`. As language data goes plenty, so as the content of the array that holds the language file does also. How would I able to put this variable to a library or as a helper then loads it something like `$this->load->library('language_data') or $this->load->helper('language_data')` in every controller file? not the array variable with lots of language data anymore to be loaded in each controller I have. Thanks a lot. Sample codes are shown below:

Controller 1:

```
class Courses extends CI_Controller {

 public $data;

 public function __construct(){
 parent::__construct();

 $this->data =array(

                    //language file for menu item
                   'dropdown'=>$this->lang->line('dropdown'),
                   'dropdownedit'=>$this->lang->line('dropdownedit'),
                   'home'=>$this->lang->line('home'),
                   'menu_desc'=>$this->lang->line('menu_desc'),
                   'login'=>$this->lang->line('login'),
                   'login_desc'=>$this->lang->line('login_desc'),
                   'teacher'=>$this->lang->line('teacher'),
                   'logout'=>$this->lang->line('logout'),


                   'course_occasion'=>$this->lang->line('course_occasion'),
                   'courses'=>$this->lang->line('courses'),
                   'student'=>$this->lang->line('student'),
                   'tennant'=>$this->lang->line('tennant'),
                   'messages'=>$this->lang->line('messages'),
                   'sent_messages'=>$this->lang->line('sent_messages'),



                    //language file for forms

                   'course_edit_form_desc'=>$this->lang->line('course_edit_form_desc'),
                   'course_reg_form_desc'=>$this->lang->line('course_reg_form_desc'),
                   'course_view_list'=>$this->lang->line('course_view_list'),
                   'view_course_available_list'=>$this->lang->line('view_course_available_list'),
                   'lbl_course_name'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_course_name'),
                   'lbl_course_desc'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_course_desc'),
                   'lbl_tennant_name'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_tennant_name'),
                   'lbl_public'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_public'),
                   'lbl_not_public'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_not_public')
    );
 }
}
```

Controller 2: (Same as controller 1)

```
class Occasions extends CI_Controller {

 public $data;

 public function __construct(){
 parent::__construct();

 $this->data =array(

                    //language file for menu item
                   'dropdown'=>$this->lang->line('dropdown'),
                   'dropdownedit'=>$this->lang->line('dropdownedit'),
                   'home'=>$this->lang->line('home'),
                   'menu_desc'=>$this->lang->line('menu_desc'),
                   'login'=>$this->lang->line('login'),
                   'login_desc'=>$this->lang->line('login_desc'),
                   'teacher'=>$this->lang->line('teacher'),
                   'logout'=>$this->lang->line('logout'),


                   'course_occasion'=>$this->lang->line('course_occasion'),
                   'courses'=>$this->lang->line('courses'),
                   'student'=>$this->lang->line('student'),
                   'tennant'=>$this->lang->line('tennant'),
                   'messages'=>$this->lang->line('messages'),
                   'sent_messages'=>$this->lang->line('sent_messages'),



                    //language file for forms

                   'course_edit_form_desc'=>$this->lang->line('course_edit_form_desc'),
                   'course_reg_form_desc'=>$this->lang->line('course_reg_form_desc'),
                   'course_view_list'=>$this->lang->line('course_view_list'),
                   'view_course_available_list'=>$this->lang->line('view_course_available_list'),
                   'lbl_course_name'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_course_name'),
                   'lbl_course_desc'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_course_desc'),
                   'lbl_tennant_name'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_tennant_name'),
                   'lbl_public'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_public'),
                   'lbl_not_public'=>$this->lang->line('lbl_not_public')
    );
 }
}
```

Desired output:

Controller 1 and Controller 2:

```
$this->load->library('language_array');
```

or

```
$this->load->helper('language_array');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure I understand you, but I think this is what you want:

Firstly create a library or helper function return the array of lang.

create a controller like:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

     public $data;

     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->library('language_array'); 
    }
}
```

So now you have a controller which loads you lib or helper item right?

Then `class Occasions extends MY_Controller` and `class Courses extends MY_Controller`, so anything that you want all your controllers to have you put in `MY_Controller` which all you other controllers inherit from.